# For strict education purposes, what exact format of bytes/bits do modern BIOS understand?

Tags: boot, bios

BIOS will look in the first 512 bytes of the first sector(at least on PC BIOS, AmeriTrend, PhoenixBIOS, etc.), and any .bin file binary formatted block of bytes will be understood by BIOS, am I correct here?

I just want to ask this to be certain, and because I want to assure that I don't make mistakes when writing my operating system carefully.

The BIOS will be executing under the processor and native-architecture obviously, so once I instruct BIOS with the binary to have the processor move the bytes in to memory I can then transfer control to my software which will then instruct the processor on what it does next, right?

I just want to know if I have this right, and I assure you this isn't spam, as I'm a curious hobbyist who has C/C++, Java, C#, x86 Assembly, and some hardware-design experience as well.

EDIT PEOPLE: I also would like to know if there's a modernized format, file, or block of bytes the BIOS must be assembled/compiled to to be executed, such as a .bin.

Comment: See [*boot sector*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector). This is an artifact of "being a PC" and not of a particular BIOS.

Comment: And by "machine code" you mean a 16-bit native flat binary .bin file of bytes on the sector? That would mean that BIOS reads machine code over the processor first. And not all EEPROM or EPROM, or any ROM is the same. BIOS works under the processor.

Comment: @pst So you're agreeing to my second response to you?

Comment: If the ROM first seeks the bytes of machine code, it reads it over (or under) the processor; it tells it what to do under its control is what I meant to say. Sorry if it came out wrong. But you're really dodging my question here originally.

Comment: I understand what a boot sector is, but you didn't agree or not to my second basic question.

Comment: I know that. Now let me rephrase my original question I asked you multiple times: What format of bytes will BIOS fetch to the processor for execution? A 16-bit ISA or MA-specific series of assembled/compiled machine code in a file known as a .bin? Is that correct?

Comment: Update the original question as appropriate.

Comment: And what format is the file the machine code is stored in? I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

As pst comment says, the boot sector is treated as i386 machine code.
The last 2 bytes need to match a special signature (0x55AA), but I think that is it as far as hard requirements.

The code just gets loaded and executed as is.

If you are trying to conform to MBR or GPT partition specs (so that other OS's can see your disk partitions) there is more to it, but that is another thing altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific "file format" for a boot sector. The BIOS simply reads the raw bytes from the boot sector, and jumps to the first instruction. It is literally just a "block of bytes", the file extension (you keep mentioning `.bin`) is not relevant at all.